# How do I delete a repeated pattern of string in a .txt file using VBScript?

Tags: replace, vbscript

Using VBScript, how could I delimit the text that starts at 'MCS4' and ends up at 'Trademark' and replace that by a white space?

Input:

```
alpha
beta 
gamma
MCS4 Copyright (c) 2018
Reg. Trademark
delta
epsilon
theta
MCS4 Copyright (c) 2018
Reg. Trademark
phi
chi 
omega
```

Desired output:

```
alpha
beta 
gamma
delta
epsilon
theta
phi
chi
```

Comment: Use the replace function. Replace that string with and empty string "".

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_replace.asp

Comment: shouldn't the output end with `omega`?

Comment: The .txt file was mentioned in the headline but wasn't described in the question. You should clarify if you want to read from one text file and write the results to (1) to the same text file (i.e. update the contents), (2) to a new text file, or (3) to the console (i.e. stdout)?

Answer (score 1):

If the string you want to remove is always the same you can use the [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954.aspx) function as [Troy Turley suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48634818/1630171). If the text between "MCS4" and "Trademark" is variable you'll need a regular expression. Note that either way you need the entire text in a single string for the replacements to work.

Using the `Replace` function:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
txt1 = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.txt").ReadAll

s = "MCS4 Copyright (c) 2018" & vbNewLine & "Reg. Trademark"

txt2 = Replace(txt1, s, "")
```

Using a regular expression replacement:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
txt1 = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.txt").ReadAll

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "MCS4[\s\S]*?Trademark"
re.Global  = True

txt2 = re.Replace(txt1, "")
```

The pattern `[\s\S]*?` matches zero or more characters that are either whitespace (`\s`) or non-whitespace (`\S`), to cover all text including newlines. The modifier `*?` ensures that you get the shortest matching sequence, so you're replacing all "MCS4...Trademark" substrings instead of the entire text between the first "MCS4" and the last "Trademark".

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_replace.asp

Replace(string,find,replacewith[,start[,count[,compare]]])

In your case, assuming the name of the string is strCopyright:

```
    Replace(strCopyright,"MCS4 Copyright (c) 2018 Reg. Trademark",""))
```